# How can I make values of the same table but of different columns share rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
 CREATE DATABASE Exam
 CREATE TABLE T1 (c1 char, c2 char)
 INSERT INTO Tenta.T1 (c1)
 VALUES ('A'), ('A'), ('B'), ('A')
 INSERT INTO Tenta.T1 (c2)
 VALUES ('B'), ('C'), ('A'), ('C')
 SELECT c1,c2
 from T1
```

OUTPUT:

```
 'A', NULL
 'A', NULL
 'B', NULL
 'A', NULL
  NULL, 'B'
  NULL, 'C'
  NULL, 'A'
  NULL, 'C'
```

I'd like the table created in such away that it´s retrieved as:

c1, c2 (columns)

A,B

A,C

B,A

A,C

That is, without the NULL values. Thanks!

Comment: What determines how the two columns are connected?

Comment: You're presuming something that _does not exist_... namely, that the rows you just inserted have any intrinsic order. The first "set" has values A,A,B,A, inserted in that order, but the database _does not care_ what order they were inserted. It's perfectly free to use B,A,A,A or A,B,A,A or any other order you can think of, unless you have some column you can use with an explicit ORDER BY expression.

Comment: choose any one of MySQL & SQL Server which is different.

Answer (score 2):

This outputs what you want if you don't care about how the data is inputted into the table

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (c1 char, c2 char);
Insert INTO T1 VALUES ('A','B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B','A'), ('A','C');
SELECT * FROM T1
```